# Web Scraping with Python - Selecting div, h2 and h3 class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is my first time with Python and web scraping. Have been looking around and still unable to get what I need to do.

Below are print screen of the elements that I've used via Chrome.

What I am trying to do is that, I am trying to get the apartment names and the address from the selected city name.

[image: List of Apartments in a selected city]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url = 'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments-for-rent/'                           
rootURL = 'http://www.homestead.ca'
response = requests.get(rootURL)                                                   
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

dropdown_list = soup.select(".primary .child-pages a")

#city_names=[dropdown_list_value.text for dropdown_list_value in dropdown_list]
#print (city_names)

cityLinks=[rootURL + dropdown_list_value['href'] for dropdown_list_value in dropdown_list]

for cityLinks_select in dropdown_list:                                       #Looping each city from the Apartment drop down list
    print ('Selecting city:',cityLinks_select.text)
    cityResponse = requests.get(cityLinks)
    cityHtml = cityResponse.content
    citySoup = BeautifulSoup(cityHtml,'lxml')

    community_list = soup.select(".extended-search .property-container a[h2 h3]")
    get and print the apartment link
    get and print the apartment name
    get and print the address of the apartment
```

Comment: You are passing a list to requests?

Comment: Hi Padraic Cunningham,

I honestly had no idea what you meant as I'm a complete newbie on this python and beautifulsoup thing. Not only that, I don't even know about html css stuff, so that makes the confusion even more interlocked in understanding.

But basically, what I need is that if I were to do it manually, I'd be clicking on the desired city that I want to see on the drop down list and see what are the available apartments and the address.

And then, clicking each of this individual to check for more details, such as what's the price for each bedroom type and how many bathroom.

Comment: You need to be iterating over the `cityLinks` list, some of the html is dynamically created, if you look at the source you can see the templates. You can only get the name, address and phone number from the source as is

Comment: so are you saying that my 2nd for loop is wrong?

Comment: We can actually get the data in json format, I will add it to my answer in a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, some of the data is dynamically created, if we look at the source itself we see:

```
                        <div class="content">
                                    <div class="title-container">
                                        <h2 class="building-name"><%= building.get('name') %></h2>
                                        <h3 class="address"><%= building.get('address').address %></h3>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="rent">
                                        <h4 class="sub-title">Rent from</h4>
                                        <% if (building.get('statistics').suites.rates.min !== 'undefined') { %>
                                            <% $min_rate = commaSeparateNumber(parseInt(building.get('statistics').suites.rates.min)); %>
                                            <span class="rent-value">$<%= $min_rate %></span>
                                        <% } %>
                                    </div>
```

All we can get from the source is the  building name, the address and the ph number:

```
cityLinks = [rootURL + dropdown_list_value['href'] for dropdown_list_value in dropdown_list]

# you need to iterate over the joined urls
for city in cityLinks:  # Looping each city from the Apartment drop down list
    cityResponse = requests.get(city)
    cityHtml = cityResponse.content
    citySoup = BeautifulSoup(cityHtml, 'lxml')
    # all the info we can parse is inside the div class="building-info"
    for div in citySoup.select("div.building-info"):
        print(div.select_one("h1.building-name").text.strip())
        print(div.select_one("h2.location").text.strip())
        print(div.select_one("div.contact-container div.phone").text.strip())
```

We can get all the data in *json* format if we mimic an ajax request:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint as pp

rootURL = 'http://www.homestead.ca'
response = requests.get(rootURL)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

dropdown_list = soup.select(".primary .child-pages a")


cityLinks = (rootURL + dropdown_list_value['href'] for dropdown_list_value in dropdown_list)

# params for our request
params = {"show_promotions": "true",
        "show_custom_fields": "true",
        "client_id": "6",
        "auth_token": "sswpREkUtyeYjeoahA2i",
        "min_bed": "-1",
        "max_bed": "100",
        "min_bath": "0",
        "max_bath": "10",
        "min_rate": "0",
        "max_rate": "4000",
        "keyword": "false",
        "property_types": "low-rise-apartment,mid-rise-apartment,high-rise-apartment,luxury-apartment,townhouse,house,multi-unit-house,single-family-home,duplex,tripex,semi",
        "order": "max_rate ASC, min_rate ASC, min_bed ASC, max_bath ASC",
        "limit": "50",
        "offset": "0",
        "count": "false"}

for city in cityLinks:  # Looping each city from the Apartment drop down list
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r= s.get(city)
        # we need to parse the city_id for out next request to work
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        city_id = soup.select_one("div.hidden.search-data")["data-city-id"]
        # update params with the city id
        params["city_id"] = city_id
        js = s.get("http://api.theliftsystem.com/v2/search", params=params).json()
        pp(js)
```

Now we get data like:

```
[{u'address': {u'address': u'325 North Park Street',
               u'city': u'Brantford',
               u'city_id': 332,
               u'country': u'Canada',
               u'country_code': u'CAN',
               u'intersection': u'',
               u'neighbourhood': u'',
               u'postal_code': u'N3R 2X4',
               u'province': u'Ontario',
               u'province_code': u'ON'},
  u'availability_count': 6,
  u'availability_status': 1,
  u'availability_status_label': u'Available Now',
  u'building_header': u'',
  u'client': {u'email': u'bcadieux@homestead.ca',
              u'id': 6,
              u'name': u'Homestead Land Holdings',
              u'phone': u'613-546-3146',
              u'website': u'www.homestead.ca'},
  u'contact': {u'alt_extension': u'',
               u'alt_phone': u'',
               u'email': u'rentals@homestead.ca',
               u'extension': u'',
               u'fax': u'(519) 752-6855',
               u'name': u'',
               u'phone': u'519-752-3596'},
  u'details': {u'features': u'',
               u'location': u'',
               u'overview': u"Located on North Park Street and Memorial Avenue,this quiet building is within walking distance of the following: - Zehrs Plaza, North Park Plaza, Shoppers Drug Mart, Zehrs Grocery Store, Zellers, Pet Store, Party Supply Store, furniture store, variety store, Black's Photography, paint shop and veterinary clinic\xa0  - Restaurants and coffee shops\xa0  - Wayne Gretzky Recreational Arena\xa0  - Medical Clinic,Shoppers Home Health Care Clinic and Pharmacy\xa0  - Catholic Elementary School\xa0  - On bus route ",
               u'suite': u''},
  u'geocode': {u'distance': None,
               u'latitude': u'43.1703624',
               u'longitude': u'-80.2605725'},
  u'id': 309,
  u'matched_beds': [u'0', u'1', u'2'],
  u'matched_suite_names': [u'Bachelor', u'One Bedroom', u'Two Bedroom'],
  u'min_availability_date': u'',
  u'name': u'North Park Tower',
  u'office_hours': u'',
  u'parking': {u'additional': u'', u'indoor': u'', u'outdoor': u''},
  u'permalink': u'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/325-north-park-street-brantford',
  u'pet_friendly': True,
  u'photo': u'1443018148_2.jpg',
  u'photo_path': u'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/full/1443018148_2.jpg',
  u'promotion': {u'featured': 0},
  u'property_type': u'High-rise-apartment',
  u'statistics': {u'suites': {u'bathrooms': {u'average': 1.0,
                                             u'max': 1.0,
                                             u'min': 1.0},
                              u'bedrooms': {u'average': u'1.0',
                                            u'max': 2,
                                            u'min': 0},
                              u'rates': {u'average': 950.0,
                                         u'max': 1275.0,
                                         u'min': 625.0},
                              u'square_feet': {u'average': 0.0,
                                               u'max': u'0.0',
                                               u'min': u'0.0'}}},
  u'thumbnail_path': u'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/256/1443018148_2.jpg',
  u'website': {u'description': u'', u'title': u'', u'url': u''}},
 {u'address': {u'address': u'661 West Street',
               u'city': u'Brantford',
               u'city_id': 332,
               u'country': u'Canada',
               u'country_code': u'CAN',
               u'intersection': u'',
               u'neighbourhood': u'',
               u'postal_code': u'N3R 6W9',
               u'province': u'Ontario',
               u'province_code': u'ON'},
  u'availability_count': 6,
  u'availability_status': 1,
  u'availability_status_label': u'Available Now',
  u'building_header': u'',
  u'client': {u'email': u'bcadieux@homestead.ca',
              u'id': 6,
              u'name': u'Homestead Land Holdings',
              u'phone': u'613-546-3146',
              u'website': u'www.homestead.ca'},
  u'contact': {u'alt_extension': u'',
               u'alt_phone': u'',
               u'email': u'rentals@homestead.ca',
               u'extension': u'',
               u'fax': u'(519) 751-0379',
               u'name': u'',
               u'phone': u'519-751-3867'},
  u'details': {u'features': u'',
               u'location': u'',
               u'overview': u'Located in the North end of Brantford, Westgate Tower is in an area that resembles a city within a city. There are a variety of banks, grocery stores, drug stores, malls, a wide selection of fast food, fine dining restaurants and an after hours medical centre, within waking distance.',
               u'suite': u''},
  u'geocode': {u'distance': None,
               u'latitude': u'43.1733242',
               u'longitude': u'-80.2482991'},
  u'id': 310,
  u'matched_beds': [u'0', u'1', u'2'],
  u'matched_suite_names': [u'Bachelor', u'One Bedroom', u'Two Bedroom'],
  u'min_availability_date': u'',
  u'name': u'Westgate Apartments',
  u'office_hours': u'',
  u'parking': {u'additional': u'', u'indoor': u'', u'outdoor': u''},
  u'permalink': u'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/661-west-street-brantford',
  u'pet_friendly': True,
  u'photo': u'1443017488_1.jpg',
  u'photo_path': u'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/full/1443017488_1.jpg',
  u'promotion': {u'featured': 0},
  u'property_type': u'High-rise-apartment',
  u'statistics': {u'suites': {u'bathrooms': {u'average': 1.0,
                                             u'max': 1.0,
                                             u'min': 1.0},
                              u'bedrooms': {u'average': u'1.0',
                                            u'max': 2,
                                            u'min': 0},
                              u'rates': {u'average': 975.0,
                                         u'max': 1300.0,
                                         u'min': 650.0},
                              u'square_feet': {u'average': 0.0,
                                               u'max': u'0.0',
                                               u'min': u'0.0'}}},
  u'thumbnail_path': u'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/256/1443017488_1.jpg',
  u'website': {u'description': u'', u'title': u'', u'url': u''}},
 {u'address': {u'address': u'321 Fairview Drive',
               u'city': u'Brantford',
               u'city_id': 332,
               u'country': u'Canada',
               u'country_code': u'CAN',
               u'intersection': u'',
               u'neighbourhood': u'',
               u'postal_code': u'N3R 2X6',
               u'province': u'Ontario',
               u'province_code': u'ON'},
  u'availability_count': 8,
  u'availability_status': 1,
  u'availability_status_label': u'Available Now',
  u'building_header': u'',
  u'client': {u'email': u'bcadieux@homestead.ca',
              u'id': 6,
              u'name': u'Homestead Land Holdings',
              u'phone': u'613-546-3146',
              u'website': u'www.homestead.ca'},
  u'contact': {u'alt_extension': u'',
               u'alt_phone': u'',
               u'email': u'rentals@homestead.ca',
               u'extension': u'',
               u'fax': u'(519) 752-6855',
               u'name': u'',
               u'phone': u'519-752-3596'},
  u'details': {u'features': u'',
               u'location': u'',
               u'overview': u'Dornia Manor is a quiet, ninety-two unit apartment building located in the North end of Brantford. We offer one, two and three bedroom units and one penthouse suite. The building is located in close proximity to many major services such as banking, shopping, health services, recreational facilities, beauty shops, dry cleaners, schools and churches. There is a bus stop at the front door and highway 403 is within minutes.',
               u'suite': u''},
  u'geocode': {u'distance': None,
               u'latitude': u'43.1706331',
               u'longitude': u'-80.2584034'},
  u'id': 308,
  u'matched_beds': [u'1', u'2', u'3'],
  u'matched_suite_names': [u'One Bedroom', u'Two Bedroom', u'Three Bedroom'],
  u'min_availability_date': u'',
  u'name': u'Dornia Manor',
  u'office_hours': u'',
  u'parking': {u'additional': u'', u'indoor': u'', u'outdoor': u''},
  u'permalink': u'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/321-fairview-drive-brantford',
  u'pet_friendly': True,
  u'photo': u'1443017947_1.jpg',
  u'photo_path': u'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/full/1443017947_1.jpg',
  u'promotion': {u'featured': 0},
  u'property_type': u'High-rise-apartment',
  u'statistics': {u'suites': {u'bathrooms': {u'average': 1.375,
                                             u'max': 2.0,
                                             u'min': 1.0},
                              u'bedrooms': {u'average': u'2.25',
                                            u'max': 3,
                                            u'min': 1},
                              u'rates': {u'average': 1124.5,
                                         u'max': 1350.0,
                                         u'min': 899.0},
                              u'square_feet': {u'average': 0.0,
                                               u'max': u'0.0',
                                               u'min': u'0.0'}}},
  u'thumbnail_path': u'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/256/1443017947_1.jpg',
  u'website': {u'description': u'', u'title': u'', u'url': u''}}]
```

That gives you the url, bedrooms and pretty much everything you could want. Each dict in the list is one listing, you just need to access using the keys to pull the data you want, for example:

```
 for dct in js:
        add = dct["address"]
        print(add["city"])
        print(add["postal_code"])
        print(add["province"])
        print(dct["permalink"])
```

Would give you:

```
Brantford
N3R 2X4
Ontario
http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/325-north-park-street-brantford
Brantford
N3R 6W9
Ontario
http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/661-west-street-brantford
Brantford
N3R 2X6
Ontario
http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/321-fairview-drive-brantford
```

The contact info is under `dct["contact"]` and the stats are under = `dct["statistics"]`:

```
for dct in js:
        contact = dct["contact"]
        print(contact)
        stats = dct["statistics"]
        print(stats["suites"])
```

Which would give you:

```
{u'alt_phone': u'', u'fax': u'(519) 752-6855', u'name': u'', u'alt_extension': u'', u'phone': u'519-752-3596', u'extension': u'', u'email': u'rentals@homestead.ca'}
{u'rates': {u'max': 1275.0, u'average': 950.0, u'min': 625.0}, u'bedrooms': {u'max': 2, u'average': u'1.0', u'min': 0}, u'bathrooms': {u'max': 1.0, u'average': 1.0, u'min': 1.0}, u'square_feet': {u'max': u'0.0', u'average': 0.0, u'min': u'0.0'}}
{u'alt_phone': u'', u'fax': u'(519) 751-0379', u'name': u'', u'alt_extension': u'', u'phone': u'519-751-3867', u'extension': u'', u'email': u'rentals@homestead.ca'}
{u'rates': {u'max': 1300.0, u'average': 975.0, u'min': 650.0}, u'bedrooms': {u'max': 2, u'average': u'1.0', u'min': 0}, u'bathrooms': {u'max': 1.0, u'average': 1.0, u'min': 1.0}, u'square_feet': {u'max': u'0.0', u'average': 0.0, u'min': u'0.0'}}
{u'alt_phone': u'', u'fax': u'(519) 752-6855', u'name': u'', u'alt_extension': u'', u'phone': u'519-752-3596', u'extension': u'', u'email': u'rentals@homestead.ca'}
{u'rates': {u'max': 1350.0, u'average': 1124.5, u'min': 899.0}, u'bedrooms': {u'max': 3, u'average': u'2.25', u'min': 1}, u'bathrooms': {u'max': 2.0, u'average': 1.375, u'min': 1.0}, u'square_feet': {u'max': u'0.0', u'average': 0.0, u'min': u'0.0'}}
```

You can put all that together to get whatever you need. Yo can tweak the params and there are actually more if you check out the request in chrome tools or firebug.

Comment: Thanks Padraic!!! Reps up to you!

Although I have no idea what you did, but that's what I need.

How did you know where to get this info...for example, I didn't see any h1 under 'building-name'

Comment: @David.L , if you have a look in the source, the `div.building-name` has all the elements above inside. Best way to find what you want is simply open the source in chrome or wherever, ctrl-f and enter what you are looking for then try to piece it all together.

Comment: Hi Padraic,
You're definitely the expert in this field.

First thing, how do I know if the data is dynamically created? Where and how did you see it? What I did with Chrome is that I highlight the value that I want, right click and choose 'inspect element'

2nd question, the params that you made, how did you get those parameters value?

3rd, what is json format and mimic an ajax request? Is there a beginner tutorial for python and this json, ajax thing so that I can learn?

Comment: @David.L, what you see when you inspect is after all requests/javascript etc.. have been completed, what you want to do is right click and choose view source, that is what you are getting when you request the page using requests. Json is for all intensive purposes like a python dictionary. http://www.w3schools.com/json/. Crack open dev tools, open the network tab and under network tab select xhr, then enter one of the urls and hit return. You will see all the requests being made, to *mimic* ajax or any requests you need to see how they are made in your browser.

Comment: Completely went over my head! But really appreciate the w3schools.com website that you showed me.

Quick question, the source has <h2 class="building-name"> and h3 class="address">. But in your python, you had print(div.select_one("h1.building-name").text.strip())  and  print(div.select_one("h2.location").text.strip()). why is it h1.building-name  and  not h2.building-name?  Also, from h2.locations.text.strip, if I want to separate the address and the city, can it be done?

Comment: It is h1 because it is a h1 header not a h2 header, you will have to ask the site designer if you want more info than that ;)   `a,b = div.select_one("h2.location").text.strip().rsplit(",", 1)` will split the add and city but I would encourage you to use the json/dicts. As far as the h1 vs h2 print the div in the loop and you will see  `<h1 class="building-name">`

Comment: Quick question Padraic, why is it that when I try to 'mimic' one of the print statement that you've made to get the suite type, my spyder hang. The one that I'm trying to 'mimic' is print(div.select_one("div.suite div.suite-type").text.strip())  where I'm trying to get the suite type

Comment: hello dear Pracraik - many thanks for your hints and solution - unfortunatley have issues to run this code ... see the rsult # ` File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\python\_examples_\homestead_ca_.py", line 21
    "max_bed": "100C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\python\_examples_
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
    "max_bed": "100C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\python\_examples_
SyntaxError: EOL ile scanning string literal [Finished in 0.26s] ` So i am wondering waht goes on with my bo